# Separatedness of open subscheme of affine schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, separation-axioms, affine-schemes

A scheme $X$ is separated if the daiganoal morphism $\Delta:X \rightarrow X \times_{\Bbb Z} X$ is a closed immersion. I know how to show that all affine schemes are separated. So

> Are open subschemes of affine schemes separated? If not, what is an example?

For example, I would be interested to know if the open subscheme
$$ D= Spec\,  k[x.y] \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow Spec \,k[x.y] $$
is separated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are. In fact, any open subscheme of a separated scheme is separated.

Let $U$ be an open subscheme of X. Base change $X\to X\times_\mathbb{Z}X$ by the map from $U\times_\mathbb{Z}U$ induced by the inclusion $U\to X$. The fiber product is just $U$, and the induced morphism is the diagonal of $U$. Since closed immersions are stable under base change, $U$ is also separated.

Comment: Your proof seems to prove that all sub-schemes of a separated scheme are separated. Is that correct? The only possible way your proof may not work for general sub-schemes is that the fibre-product may only topologically be U, but scheme theoretically it might be different. But I think separated-ness is a purely topological property and hence it shouldn't matter if we get the same scheme as U as the fibre product or not and hence the proof should still work. Is that correct? Thanks in advance!